# Complex word search multiple files using Python

Tags: python, search, row

This is probably going to be the hardest thing I've had to explain haha. This is what I need to be able to do:

Start with word inside ws1 ['A1][28:] (example word 'A115' this word always changes as the script loops through each file.)

Open ws4 search row B (no header) for ws1['A1'][28:] (A115)

Once word (A115) is located in ws4 row B locate word that is 9 cells below it (example 'N90111.90' word always changes as script loops) then take that word and

open ws5 and find that word (N90111.90) under column A (no header) once that word is found go horizontally from that word (N90111.90) to column L and copy that value (20.22) and convert it from Miles to Ft. (106761.6) and then paste that value inside
ws3 column O row 2 (106761.6).

```
import openpyxl as xl 
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
 
 
input_dir = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\NNM'
Summary = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\Summary.xlsx'
TLL = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\TLL.xlsx'
NDE = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\NDE.xlsx'
newFile = 'Comparison.xlsx'
 
 
 
 
files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir)
         if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".xlsx")]
 
i=0
ii=0
 
wb3=xlsxwriter.Workbook(newFile)
ws3=wb3.add_worksheet('Comparison')
 
 
format = wb3.add_format()
format.set_align('center')
format.set_align('vcenter')
format.set_bold(True)
format.set_font_size(14)
format.set_bg_color('#C9C9C9')
format.set_border(style=1)
 
 
ws3.write('F2:', '=C2-E2')
 
ws3.write_row("A1:Q1", ['T','Segment','Chainage(ft)','Segment','Chainage(ft)','Start Chainage Difference(ft)','Segment','Chainage(ft)','Segment','Chainage(ft)','End Chainage Difference(ft)','Stops','Stops','Distance','Distance','Distance Difference (ft)','Comments'], format)
ws3.set_column(1, 17, 35)
wb3.close()
 
wb3 = xl.load_workbook(newFile) 
ws3 = wb3.worksheets[0]
 
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(Summary) 
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[1]
 
wb4 = xl.load_workbook(TLL) 
ws4 = wb4.worksheets[0]
 
wb5 = xl.load_workbook(NDE) 
ws5 = wb5.worksheets[0]
 
 
for file in files: 
   input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
   wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
   ws1=wb1.worksheets[0]
    
 
   series = pd.read_excel(file,usecols = "F",squeeze = True)
   counts = series.value_counts()
   z = counts[0]/2
 
 
   ws3[f'A{i+2}']=ws1['A1'].value[28:]
   ws3[f'D{i+2}']=ws1['B4'].value
   ws3[f'E{i+2}']=ws1['D4'].value
   ws3[f'I{i+2}']=ws1['B'][-1].value
   ws3[f'J{i+2}']=ws1['D'][-1].value
   ws3[f'O{i+2}']=ws1['E'][-1].value 
   ws3[f'N{i+2}']=ws2[f'I{ii+6}'].value   
   ws3[f'M{i+2}']=z
    
   i += 1
   ii +=1          
    
 
 
   wb3.save(newFile)
```

Comment: You like totally forgot to add what the problem is with your code.

Comment: The code doesn't have errors.  I just don't know how to start when it comes to implementing what I want to do.